# After splitting up of react hooks components, the search is not working anymore

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been doing a bit of refactoring the code, splitting up of some of the existing big components in react. Earlier the search was working fine, now after splitting it doesn't work as expected. I have created  separate component called `searchBox` and imported into `blogItem` component. Eventually the blogItem component is imported into Home.js
Could someone please advise why the search is not performing here  ?

CSB link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-james-t599p2?file=/src/blogItem.js

searchBox.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const SearchBox = () => {
  const SearchArea = useCallback(
    ({ value, onChange }) => (
      <div className="searchArea">
        {/* {isPortrait ? "" : ""} */}
        <div className="row">
          <div className="searchbox">
            <div className="sboxcolumnn-1">
              <img src="images/search.png" />
            </div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="searchbox"
              placeholder="search blogs..."
              value={value}
              onChange={onChange}
            ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ),
    []
  );

  return <SearchArea />;
};

export default SearchBox;
```

blogItem.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import SearchBox from "./searchBox";

const blogData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    date: "25 Jan 2023",
    photo: "https://picsum.photos/80",
    heading: "Cypress setup blog",
    blogDetails:
      "Best heading added here. The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Wont be a good idea play here always."
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date: "22 Jan 2022",
    photo: "https://picsum.photos/80",
    heading: "React state details",
    blogDetails:
      "Best heading added here. The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Wont be a good idea play here always."
  }
];

const BlogItem = ({ id, date, photo, heading, blogDetails }) => {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  /* Send a GET request to server and get the blog data from contentful website and display in the Home page */
  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchResults(blogData);
  }, []);

  /* Type the blog text in the search box, system will filter the blog post based on the search criteria in the Home page */
  const results = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      searchResults.filter((blog) => {
        return (
          blog.heading.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
          blog.heading.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm)
        );
      }),
    [searchTerm, searchResults]
  );

  const Columns = () => (
    <div className="blogItems">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="blogArea">
          {results.map(({ id, date, photo, heading, blogDetails }) => (
            <a key={id}>
              <div
                className="blogImageSection"
                onClick={
                  () =>
                    navigate("blogDetails", {
                      state: { id, date, photo, heading, blogDetails }
                    }) // this is how to pass data with useNavigate
                }
              >
                <img alt="id" src={photo} />
                <div key={id} className="dataArea">
                  <span className="dataDate">{date}</span>
                  <span className="tags">cypress</span>
                  <h3>{heading}</h3>
                  <p>
                    Best heading added here. The most relevant data added here.
                    Greatest of all time. Wont be a good idea play here always.
                  </p>
                  <a href="_blank" className="readmoreLink">
                    Read more →
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <>
      <SearchBox value={searchTerm} onChange={handleChange} />
      <Columns />
    </>
  );
};

export default BlogItem;
```

Home.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import BlogItem from "./blogItem";
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div id="App">
      <BlogItem />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing props to the `SearchBox` but not using them since you are using a `useCallback` inside that component and returning that. Which won't work.

If you remove the `useCallback` and just run the Searchbox with proper props it'll work.

Here's what I did:

```
const SearchBox = ({value, onChange}) => {
  return <div className="searchArea">
        ...rest of input code as is
      </div>
}

export default SearchBox;
```

If you need to optimize it, use `memo` and memoize the whole component.

Although you really don't need to memoize it as long as the value and onChange stay the same it won't re-render.

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-dubinsky-9t66ym?file=/src/searchBox.js